# Updating background worker to async-await

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, backgroundworker

So this is how I currently use background worker to save a lot of stuff to file while presenting the user with a progress bar and preventing any changes to the UI while saving is in progress. I think I've captured the essential features. The modal `ProgressWindow` displays a progress bar and not much else.  How would I go about changing this to `async-await` pattern, if I had to?

```
private ProgressForm ProgressWindow { get; set; }

/// <summary>On clicking save button, save stuff to file</summary>
void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    if (!BackgroundWorker.IsBusy)
    {
      BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(SaveFileDialog.FileName);
      ProgressWindow= new ProgressForm();
      ProgressWindow.SetPercentageDone(0);
      ProgressWindow.ShowDialog(this);
    }
  }
}

/// <summary>Background worker task to save stuff to file</summary>
void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  string path= e.Argument as string;

  // open file

  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // get some stuff from UI
    // save stuff to file
    BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
  }

  // close file
}

/// <summary>On background worker progress, report progress</summary>
void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ProgressWindow.SetPercentageDone(e.ProgressPercentage);
}

/// <summary>On background worker finished, close progress form</summary>
void BackgroundWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ProgressWindow.Close();
}
```

Comment: Well, start with removing your backgroundworker, then checking out this page. [Await Async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: To report progress using async, you use `IProgress<T>`. [See here for more info](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html).

Comment: @Watson @ChristophKn My problem is that there doesn't seem to be anything for me to `await`

Comment: If you use `File` class's static methods, there is nothing to await. But note that all file stream related methods have their async versions, which you can of course await. Just need to change the way you program such operations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have a [blog series](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html) that covers this in detail.

In short, `BackgroundWorker` is replaced by `Task.Run`, and `ReportProgress` (and friends) is replaced by `IProgress<T>`.

So, a straightforward translation would look like this:

```
async void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    ProgressWindow = new ProgressForm();
    ProgressWindow.SetPercentageDone(0);
    var progress = new Progress<int>(ProgressWindow.SetPercentageDone);
    var task = SaveAndClose(SaveFileDialog.FileName, progress));
    ProgressWindow.ShowDialog(this);
    await task;
  }
}

async Task SaveAndClose(string path, IProgress<int> progress)
{
  await Task.Run(() => Save(path, progress));
  ProgressWindow.Close();
}

void Save(string path, IProgress<int> progress)
{
  // open file

  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // get some stuff from UI
    // save stuff to file
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(i);
  }

  // close file
}
```

Notes for improvements:

- It's not usually a good idea to have background threads reaching into the UI (`// get some stuff from UI`). It would probably work better if you could collect all the information from the UI *before* calling `Task.Run` and just pass it into the `Save` method.

Comment: Unfortunately `ProgressWindow.ShowDialog(this);` will not give you a chance to `await task` and close the dialog.

Comment: I have been dipping in and out of your blog, but its useful to see things in the context of my own code. One of my problems is that the most time consuming part is the part that gathers the information from the UI (more so than writing to the file). Since it is all read only I've "got away with it" I think. I wonder how things would change if I was reading from a file and writing to the UI. Looking forward to your solution to Ivan's point!

Comment: @Graham: The code has been updated; `SaveAndClose` properly handles closing `ProgressWindow` from within `ProgressWindow.ShowDialog` (man, I hate nested message loops!). I am still skeptical about reading UI values from a background thread; especially since I/O is generally much, much slower than in-memory operations.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for your help. I ended up not using async or await at all (because there was nothing to wait for, or if there was, there was nothing to do while waiting anyway). And also the modal progress bar did that job. I just used `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Invoke` to get stuff from the UI. The background worker pattern still does it for me though. Perhaps it's just what I'm used to!

Answer (score 4):

I guess the reason why you let another thread do the time consuming stuff is because you want to keep the user interface responsive. Your method will meet this requirement.

The advantage of using async-await is that the code will look more synchronous, while the user interface seems to be responsive. You don't have to work with events and functions like Control.IsInvokeRequired, because it is the main thread that will do the work.

The disadvantage of async-await is that as long as the main thread is really doing something (= not awaiting for a task to finish), your UI is not responsive.

Having said that, making a function async is easy:

- declare the function async
- Instead of void return Task and instead of TResult return Task < TResult >.
- The only exception to this rule are event handlers. An async event handler returns void.
- Do your stuff sequentially and whenever possible call async versions of other functions.
- Calling this async function does not execute it immediately. Instead it is scheduled to be executed as soon as a thread in the pool of available thread is ready to do so.
- This means that after your thread scheduled the task it is free to do other things

  - When your thread needs the result of the other task await for the tak.
  - The return of await Task is void, the return of await Task < TResult > is TResult.

So to make your function async:

The async SaveFile function is easy:

```
private async Task SaveFileAsync(string fileName)
{   // this async function does not know
    // and does not have to know that a progress bar is used
    // to show its process. All it has to do is save
    ...
    // prepare the data to save, this may be time consuming
    // but this is not the main thread, so UI still responding
    // after a while do the saving and use other async functions
    using (TextWriter writer = ...)
    {
        var writeTask = writer.WriteAsync (...)
        // this thread is free to do other things,
        // for instance prepare the next item to write
        // after a while wait until the writer finished writing:
        await writeTask;

        // of course if you had nothing to do while writing
        // you could write:
        await writer.WriteAsync(...)
    }
```

The SaveButtonClick async is also easy. Because of all my comment it seems a lot of code, but in fact it is a small function.

Note that the function is an event handler: return void instead of Task

```
private async void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // start a task to save the file, but don't wait for it to finish
        // because we need to update the progress bar
        var saveFileTask = Task.Run () => SaveFileAsync ( SaveFileDialog.FileName );
```

The task is scheduled to run as soon as a thread in the thread pool is free.
Meanwhile the main thread has time to do other things, like showing and updating the progress window.

```
        this.ProgressWindow.Visible = true;
        this.ProgressWindow.Value = ...
```

Now repeatedly wait a sec and adjust progress. Stop as soon as the saveFileTask task is finished.

We can't just let the main thread wait for the task to finish because that would stop UI from being responsive, besides the main thread should repeatedly update the progressbar.

Solution: Don't use the Task.Wait functions, but the Task.When functions. The difference is that Task.When functions return awaitable Tasks, and thus you can await for the task to finish, thus keeping the UI responsive.

The Task.When funcitons don't have a timeout version. For this we start a Task.Delay

```
    while (!fileSaveTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        await Task.WhenAny( new Task[]
        {
            fileSaveTask,
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        };
        if (!fileSaveTask.IsCompleted
           this.UpdateProgressWindow(...);
    }
```

The Task.WhenAny stops as soon as the fileSaveTask is completed, or if the delay task is completed.

Things to do: react on errors if fileSave encounters problems. Consider returning a Task < TResult > instead of Task.

```
TResult fileSaveResult = fileSaveTask.Result;
```

or throw an exception. The main window thread catches this as an AggregateException. The InnerExceptions (plural) contain the exceptions thrown by any of the tasks.

If you need to be able to stop the saving process, you need to pass a CacellationToken to every function and let the SaveFile

Comment: Actually I show a modal dialog with a progress bar in order to show the user that information is being saved while preventing the user from changing anything at the same time. So in fact I want the main form to be unresponsive but in a way that allows it to refresh. Also writing to the file is not at all time consuming compared to reading from the UI so `WriteAsync` doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: My answer was not meant as an answer for only your specific problem, but as an example for similar problems where you want to know how to change the use of a backgroundworker into the use of async-await

Answer (score 2):

[Stephen Cleary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314702/updating-background-worker-to-async-await/35316334#35316334) basically covers the case. But there is one complication imposed by the blocking `ShowDialog` call which prevents the normal `async/await` flow.

So in addition to his answer I would suggest you the following general helper function

```
public static class AsyncUtils
{
    public static Task ShowDialogAsync(this Form form, IWin32Window owner = null)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        EventHandler onShown = null;
        onShown = (sender, e) =>
        {
            form.Shown -= onShown;
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        };
        form.Shown += onShown;
        SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => form.ShowDialog(owner), null);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Then remove the `ProgressWindow` form member and use the following

```
async void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (var progressWindow = new ProgressForm())
        {
            progressWindow.SetPercentageDone(0);
            await progressWindow.ShowDialogAsync(this);
            var path = SaveFileDialog.FileName;
            var progress = new Progress<int>(progressWindow.SetPercentageDone);
            await Task.Run(() => Save(path, progress));
        }
    }
}

static void Save(string path, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    // as in Stephen's answer
}
```

Note that I've marked the actual worker method `static`, to prevent the access to the form (and any UI element) inside and work only with the passed arguments.

Comment: Your answer is good and worked (Because Cleary's `ProgressWindow.Close();` does not work), but your explanation was a little ambiguous. Just to clarify based on what worked for me: 1) I implemented your `AsyncUtils` class as-is. 2) I moved the call to `ProgressWindow.Close();` to a point right after the line of code: `await Task.Run(() => Save(path, progress))` in the method `SaveButtonClick`. 3) I did away with Cleary's `SaveAndClose` method.